# Replace cells in row if condition met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to for Less, Middle Greater columns. If it is greater than 0 to replace the ROW with 1. So the top row would become?

```
                  Conc      Less    Middle   Greater
Date                                                
2005-03-02 00:00  10.3  0.000000  1         1
```

This is the original

```
                  Conc      Less    Middle   Greater
Date                                                
2005-03-02 00:00  10.3  0.000000  0.083333  0.916667

2005-03-02 01:00  14.1  0.000000  0.750000  0.250000

2005-03-02 02:00   7.0  0.000000  0.833333  0.166667

2005-03-02 03:00   7.0  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000

2005-03-02 04:00   7.2  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000

2005-03-02 06:00   6.6  0.333333  0.666667  0.000000

2005-03-02 07:00   6.6  0.416667  0.583333  0.000000
```

i've tried:

```
df.loc[df['Less']>0:]=1
df.loc[df['Less']==0:]=0
```

but that shows up in red and says False True (In the correct places) and:
dtype: bool, None, None)

I also tried: looping through like:

```
for line in df['Less']:
    if df['Less'] >0:
        df['Less']=1
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `loc` with boolean condition:

```
In [250]:
df.loc[df['Less'] > 0, 'Less'] = 1
df

Out[250]:
                     Conc  Less    Middle   Greater
Date                                               
2005-03-02 00:00:00  10.3   0.0  0.083333  0.916667
2005-03-02 01:00:00  14.1   0.0  0.750000  0.250000
2005-03-02 02:00:00   7.0   0.0  0.833333  0.166667
2005-03-02 03:00:00   7.0   0.0  1.000000  0.000000
2005-03-02 04:00:00   7.2   0.0  1.000000  0.000000
2005-03-02 06:00:00   6.6   1.0  0.666667  0.000000
2005-03-02 07:00:00   6.6   1.0  0.583333  0.000000
```

this `df.loc[df['Less']>0:]` is invalid syntax, you want to use a comma and pass the list of column names of interest

Your `for` loop version:

```
for line in df['Less']:
    if df['Less'] >0:
        df['Less']=1
```

is invalid because `if` doesn't understand how to interpret an array of boolean values hence the error, if you did `if (df['Less'] >0).all()` or `if (df['Less'] >0).any()` then it would be happy but it doesn't make sense anyway as you're iterating row-wise but then testing the entire df which is wasteful.

Comment: Cheers, that seems to have worked
Aaah okay, I tried it witth .any() but that assumed that the whole df was true, even when only one was.

Answer (score 0):

To do them all at once:

```
columns = ['Less', 'Middle', 'Greater']
df[columns] = np.where(df[columns] >0, 1 ,0)
```

Or to do it individually (Note double brackets for selecting columns):

```
df[['Less']] = np.where(df[['Less']] >0, 1 ,0)
df[['Middle']] = np.where(df[['Middle']] >0, 1 ,0)
df[['Greater']] = np.where(df[['Greater']] >0, 1 ,0)
```

Comment: np is numpy import btw